# All content with position: relative is hidden once button has focus in overflow-y:auto parent container

Tags: html, css, focus, overflow, accessibility

I am creating an accessible chat window for use in a project. The buttons must be focusable to perform actions on each message. It's working OK without focus on the buttons BUT focus is an accessibility requirement.

It's an obscure use case where all content disappears once buttons are focussed. This appears to be the case only if the button parent has a `position:relative` set on it.

Has anyone encountered this? I would first prefer advice that is CSS only.

Is visible in: Firefox and Chrome

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/gkweb/full/YrEVYV/)

```css
    .container {
      width: 20em;
      height: 20em;
      padding: 1em;
      background-color: darkgreen;
    }
    
    .container > div {
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 100%;
      backgorund-color: purple;
    }

    .container ul {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .container ul > li {
      display: block;
      padding: .5em;
      margin: 0 0 2em;
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
    }

    .container ul > li button {
      position: absolute;
      top: -999em;
      right: -999em;
    }

    .container ul > li button:focus {
      outline: 2px solid purple;
    }

    .container ul > li:hover button,
    .container ul > li button:focus {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

    .message-inner {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
HTML And CSS:

    <div class="container">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="message-inner">
                <span class="text">Content of item in here is big bg big</span>
                <span class="date">1/1/11</span>
                <button> some action</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by removing the following from your CSS:

```
.container ul > li button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  right: -999em;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLVwaE?editors=1100#0) for a demo.

MS Edge doesn't seem to have any issued with this tho, only Firefox and Chrome.

As I see it, you're trying to hide buttons, until the parent `li` is focused. And in order to keep in "accessible", you're removing it from view by adding the above mentioned code. So how about [this solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEOoRm?editors=1100#0), utilizing `opacity` and `pointer-events` instead?

Comment: Thank you, This partially fixes the issue but with the design I'm adhering -  It needed be positioned absolutely over the content.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up fixing via:

```
.container ul > li button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  right: 0; // fix
}
```

My guess is that these browsers (Chrome, Firefox) were interpreting the right: -999em to be ALL content in the container therefore hiding it accordingly.